# Loading template file and replacing placeholders

Tags: php, template

I have an HTLP template file called "template.tmpl". In the template I have a few placeholders like `{{NAME}}` and `{{USERNAME}}`. I am then loading the template file into a variable called $template using `file_get_contents`. I then put the `$template` variable through a function which deals with replacing a series of placeholders.

My code is below and seems to be working fine, but wanted some input if there was any way to improve or make it more efficient.

```
function replace_tags($string){
    $vars = array('{{NAME}}'=>'Bob', '{{USERNAME}}'=>'user_name', '<?'=>'', '?>'=>'');
    return str_replace(array_keys($vars), $vars, $string);
}

$template = file_get_contents('template.tmpl', true);

echo replace_tags($template);
```

Comment: Please post real code that you use, not example code. If you build a template that you always use with "Bob" and "user_name", why did you bother making the template?

Comment: I havent finished the full thing yet, this is the start to building a template parsing script.

Comment: I think you should hold off on asking this question until you're a bit further along with the process. Right now there's not much we can do - keep in mind that most of the time, code reviews are about improving the code without changing the output.

Comment: For example, replace_tags could end like it is now, cleaning items from a template. It could also end up as a massive function which needs 30 arguments to put in place of placeholders. You'll get very different reviews on questions like those... I think you'll get answers that help you more if you have a bit more functionality to show. It will also help in determining what the eventual goal is with what you're trying to create.

Answer (score 5):

I would say suggest writing your input like so:

```
function replace_tags($template, $placeholders){
    $placeholders = array_merge($placeholders, array('<?'=>'', '?>'=>''));
    return str_replace(array_keys($placeholders), $placeholders, $template);
}

$vars = array('{{NAME}}'=>'Bob', '{{USERNAME}}'=>'user_name');
$template = file_get_contents('template.tmpl', true);

echo replace_tags($template, $vars);
```

So that you can define the constant changes, and the changes you want to build depending on user, etc.